# ASP.NET MVC Custom Controller directory

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm making an ASP.NET MVC website and I have a certain group of forms that are related (let's called them Foo).  My first attempt to organized them was to have this structure:

```
Controllers/FooController.cs
```

...and to have routes like this:

```
Foo/{type}/{action}/{id}
```

Unfortunately, since there are about 8 Foo sub-types, the `FooController` was getting quite large and containing it's own sub-routing information.  My next stab at it was to have this structure:

```
Controllers/Foo/Form1Controller.cs
Controllers/Foo/Form2Controller.cs
Controllers/Foo/Form3Controller.cs
...
```

With a controller for each form, which makes more sense to me since that's basically the layout I use for other forms in the app.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any easy way to make the route:

```
Foo/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

...map to:

```
Controllers/Foo/{controller}Controller.cs
```

Basically what I want to do is tell ASP.NET MVC that I want all routes that match the Foo route to look in the `Foo` subfolder of `Controllers` for their controllers.  Is there any easy way to do that via routing, or do I need to write my own `IControllerFactory`?

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldnt Controllers/Foo/Form1Controller.aspx be Controllers/Foo/Form1Controller.cs? Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Right right, but the question is still the same.  I'll fix now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using a variation of the solution discussed here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx

Comment: Good simple find.  Supposed to be built in the next version of MVC.

Comment: Yeah, I was pretty surprised that it was this complicated.  However, I guess it is only at 1.0.

Comment: @cdmckay Not that I think Haacked's site would ever go down or disappear but could you summarize on Stackoverflow to keep content consistent?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [SubControllers](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/mvccontrib-now-with-subcontroller-support/).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try RouteConstraint? It is not about directories rather controller names but very simple - you should try:

```
routes.MapRoute("FooControllers",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" },
    new { controller = @"(Form1)|(Form2)|(Form3)" }
);
```

or:

```
routes.MapRoute("FooControllers",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" },
    new { controller = @"Form[1..8]" }
);
```

Comment: This still won't let me have my Foo forms in a subfolder under Controllers.